# Oracle Application Express empty edit page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new to APEX. When I create pages in my app the edit pages that generate automatically work for some pages but not for others - they are blank except for the Create, Delete, Cancel buttons and the PK item (but that one's "Hidden"). There are no other items. I tried to add them manually but they don't connect to the respective rows - when I try to edit a row in the app it displays [empty lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSNdQ.png)

Consequentially, I also can't delete any rows. I tried to compare everything in the settings of pages that have working edit pages but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the simplest option is to create either

- a form on a table with report whose wizard will create

  - an interactive report you'd use to *view* data; enable you to modify existing records using the "edit" icon at the beginning of each row; create new records using the <kbd>Create</kbd> button
  - a form used to modify and create new records
- a tabular form (or an interactive grid) that enables you do do *everything* (insert, update delete) on the same page

If you create a form by yourself, you should create required processes which do different actions. I'm lazy to do it manually, so I *always* let the Wizard do the dirty job.

From your description, it seems that you created a form, included several items, possibly set them to be *database items*, but Apex doesn't know how to retrieve existing records (something like *execute query* in Oracle Forms). Therefore, try to use one of options I suggested and see how they behave.

Comment: I'm using the wizard to make a Report with Form on Table and it doesn't properly generate the edit form

Comment: I can't remember that it ever failed. Did you properly set everything the Wizard asked? Primary key?

Comment: Okay, I did everything the same and just changed the type of grid to interactive at the beggining and it started working somehow